# How to disable Google Talk on Android Prestige ZTE

Tags: google-talk

I've been trying since forever to do it. How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This can help to answer the question by picking up where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

Root the mobile, search on XDA forum on how to root your particular device. Every device rooting technique is different... Go through comments, reviews before rooting..
Once you have successfully rooted, download application eg: "system app remover" or similar apps. Open the app and now you uninstall your google talk app.

It is not possible without root because it is a system app & you require sudo permission to uninstall it. In upgraded version of mobiles these days there is option to disable system apps.

Comment: This answer, in its' current form, is a bit short. To improve this answer I suggest adding an example of *how to uninstall the system app* and *why disabling is not possible*.

Comment: Edited the answer..  I hope you remove the downvote and upvote it

Comment: The downvote was not mine, but I upvoted your answer because it basically answered the very general question.